# How to have code reuse when using union types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am learning about union types by reading [this section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) of the documentation.

The code used to demonstrate union types is this:

```
interface Bird {
  fly(): void;
  layEggs(): void;
}

interface Fish {
  swim(): void;
  layEggs(): void;
}

declare function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird;

let pet = getSmallPet();
pet.layEggs();
```

And the following comment was made about using union types:

> In traditional object-oriented code, we might abstract over the two
> types by creating a hierarchy of types. While this is much more
> explicit, it’s also a little bit overkill.

The traditional object-oriented code being alluded to might look like this:

```
class Animal {
  layEggs(): void {console.log("laying eggs")};
}

class Bird extends Animal {
  fly(): void {console.log("flying")};
}

class Fish extends Animal {
  swim(): void {console.log("swimming")};
}

declare function getSmallPet(): Animal;


let pet = getSmallPet();
pet.layEggs();
```

One benefit I see in the traditional object-oriented code, is the ability to have code reuse. For example the similar `layEggs` implementation can be moved to the super class, instead of being repeated in both the sub class.

I have not been able to find a way to achieve similar code reuse when using union types in typescript. Are there ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a union when you want to have some enumerated list of possibilities, especially one that can be easily [discriminated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) by a common property.  Union types don't prevent you from having code reuse, with or without `class` hierarchies. The concepts are somewhat orthogonal.

For example, we can have `getSmallPet()` put together an object assignable to the `Fish` or `Bird` interfaces with no class hierarchy, but still reuse code:

```
function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
  const eggLayer = { layEggs() { console.log("LAYING EGGS") } };
  const flier = { fly() { console.log("FLYING") } };
  const swimmer = { swim() { console.log("SWIMMING") } };
  return Object.assign(eggLayer, Math.random() < 0.5 ? flier : swimmer);
}
```

Here the same code is being used for the `layEggs()` method regardless of whether the returned object is piscine or avian in nature.

---

As another example, you could decide to implement a class hierarchy the way you've done, but this does not preclude you from using a union type.  Imagine that `getSmallPet()` is implemented like this:

```
function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? new Fish() : new Bird()
};
```

You're not getting an unspecific `Animal` out of that; you're either getting a `Fish` or a `Bird`.

---

While both the `Animal` and `Fish | Bird` types let you call the `layEggs()` method:

```
let pet = getSmallPet();
pet.layEggs(); // LAYING EGGS;
```

Only the union type `Fish | Bird` can be so easily probed via type guard to achieve the equivalent of downcasting:

```
if ("swim" in pet) {
  pet.swim(); // SWIMMING, or maybe
} else { // notice, just "else" here, not "else if"
  pet.fly(); // FLYING
}
```

If you just had an `Animal`, you'd have to check `instanceof Bird` and `instanceof Fish` and have a third clause that does something like `throw()` if your `Animal` turns out to be some other species.  With `Fish | Bird` you know that if it can't `swim()` then it can definitely `fly()`.

---

In summary, you can have union types with or without code reuse and with or without class hierarchies; it might be best to think of them separately.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gYQDYilaSA3gLABQZSSAlsAC4QBOAZgsgEJUMAmRFlSTLAE8AFAEoAXEgBuaKlwDcfSjiEBRAOYao4qbPlLSlAL5k+Nes1ZIAYlSgALXkf5QA7lTC6ZcxcqSqmtre+n4upuQuTACuwPC0VGjASBoQtADKYCBYWAAKad52jkgAPkgc3M78SPBJULRIEFoAMiBCjEgAvEQBbUE6Yj21wFBoWBAAdFhoGiIARM0AggCaAJIoAOJIahsb6XODxkjGhtXD9QJYVB3dhJeig3fnY5PTs3M2zWubB8fHp-xzg13J5IAwuj0QV5HjU6i8pjN5ukAOqrACyaPWG1+RxO-gYaWiDGSAHkAEYAKwg8QmuCgVA0wBETQ0rXaDAANEg0SBaA4JgwQMAuGhoUgADxIAAMEwArEgAPyXa7gqRQsFiAERPjjBowNIQ1IZLI5fK0cQA-W0KZ9LQDBRIAD0jqQS2+Wx2e0M5iYSHmULm1GSVse-itEyhFqdLpR6Mxmy5aHBWSEZIgfCOECw+Cq-HDggeDudti+WIzZG1pFAkFg1mwdIIJBc8BweCQi2AnmyuZUtuCkh88iGcPGCPeqhoGkadpxWrMzdbUHKnB4EAAHvRhUuO12sD37iFfMORvC3vMC5PZ+XIpQW3TbPYnOvN1xt52TfvIwPQsfRqOz3M6qXocc43gIsTxIkyRGpk2R5AUA5FE4ZQVDwTbVAStBEskPJ8gKQoimKkoyvKSrABAbgPo44hIFI5GUah4gZt6Li6kgVqGmksGmghlppDa6h2haPp+oBHhgIGNDsWkoYuJQ4ZfkWLpAcAGiJsmbRphmjTZsg6F5vxBZRsWF6qdexhAA)